# How to get a reference to a web form's ModelStateDictionary from inside a Web Forms MVP Presenter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webformsmvp

Using the [Web Forms MVP](https://github.com/webformsmvp/webformsmvp) framework in an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms application, how do I get a reference to a page's [ModelStateDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.modelstate(v=vs.110).aspx) object from inside the `Presenter` object for that page?

I'd like my presenter to be able to set model state errors when something goes wrong. For example: errors when attempting to insert records that violate a UNIQUE constraint.

```
try
{
    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException updateException)
{
    // how to get a reference to the model state?
    ModelStateDictionary state = null;

    // add the error to the model state for display by the view
    state.AddModelError("key", updateException.GetBaseException().Message);
}
```

A google search for "[webformsmvp presenter modelstatedictionary](https://www.google.com/#q=webformsmvp%20presenter%20modelstatedictionary)" yields an alarmingly low number of relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to pass the model state from the view to the presenter as an event argument.

First, the `EventArgs` class:

```
public class ModelStateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ModelStateEventArgs(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        this.ModelState = modelState;
    }

    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; private set; }
}
```

derive from this class if you need additional event arguments

---

Then, the `IView` that is implemented by the view:

```
public interface IDataContextView : IView<DataContextVM>
{
    event EventHandler<ModelStateEventArgs> Update;
}
```

---

Raising the event in the view itself:

- `MvpPage` views

  ```
  this.Update(this, new ModelStateEventArgs(this.ModelState));
  ```
- `MvpUserControl` views

  ```
  this.Update(this, new ModelStateEventArgs(this.Page.ModelState));
  ```

---

Finally, the `Presenter`, which can subscribe to the `Update` events and get the model state for each event as it happens:

```
public class DataContextPresenter : Presenter<IDataContextView>
{
    public DataContextPresenter(IDataContextView view)
        : base(view)
    {
        this.View.Update += OnUpdating();
    }

    private void OnUpdating(object sender, ModelStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = ConvertViewModelToEntity(this.View.Model);
        dbcontext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException updateException)
        {
            // add the error to the model state for display by the view
            e.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, updateException.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
    }
}
```